# Use of word "axiom" in definition of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, definition, axioms

Consider the following definition of vector spaces:

[image: vector space definition]

Why are the listed conditions called "axioms"? My understanding of axioms is that they are base assumptions which are taken to be true. Thus, they're not really meant to be proven. Yet from this definition, it's necessary to show that the axioms are "satisfied" for a specific set in order to conclude that the set is a vector space. Is that somehow different than "proving" the axioms are true for the given set?

Comment: An axiom describes criteria for being included in a certain club. A theorem describes what privileges membership in the club awards its members. Proving a theorem means showing that someone has certain privileges. If the privilege under consideration is one of the privileges awarded the members of a certain club, one way of showing that someone has this privilege (i.e. that a theorem applies to an object) is verifying that he/she is a member of the club (i.e., that the object satisfies the axioms).

Comment: Suppose you have the axioms for a vector space.  Then I dumped my dirty laundry on your floor and said "here, this is a vector space" and you said "no, it's not.  It doesn't satisfy *any* of the conditions for being a vector space" and I said "they're axiomatic! I don't have to prove them.  I can assume they are true".  Well, I can assume they are true if I *know* it is a vector space, but if I don't know it is a vector space I have to prove it.  And I do it by showing that in this case the hold.  Or in the case of my dirty laundry they don't.  If they hold, it's a vector space.

Comment: In addition to the good answers here, I'd like to add that this is a pattern you'll see in different fields.  1) Here are a list of properties. 2) Can we find an example of a thing that has those properties? 3) What can we prove about things in general that have these properties?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Axioms in modern mathematics means the same as a set of properties, or conditions. Different things may or may not satisfy them. When you define a vector space you are basically saying that a vector space is anything which satisfies those axioms. The axioms are not intended to have any deeper meaning than that. They simply single out some things among all by listing properties. It's simply a definition. In the olden days, some philosophers and teachers insisted on attaching some vague unverifiable truth to the notion of axiom. That is long gone (or should be).

Comment: "That is long gone." I'd say that this is true, except in the case of "foundational" axioms like ZF, ZFC, etc, where we want to have some intuitive notion of truth to attach to them, because they're forming the foundation of all of mathematics.

Comment: I also feel that this is true of theories with an intended model, notably PA. PA is not just a set of arbitrary statements where we care about all its structures equally; PA describes truths of the natural numbers.

Comment: They are axioms, in that they are things taken as unproven about the theory of vector spaces *within the theory of vector spaces*.  The definition bit can be reinterpreted as *if you prove the axioms* about your arbitrary thing, you also get the entire theory of vector spaces "for free".

Comment: Your "should be" is too reductive. It's all very well studying the algebraic structure of the cartesian cube of the unique complete ordered field, but if you want to be able to use that to claim that the diagonal of a square bathroom tile should be about 1.4 times the length of the side, the "classical" axiomatic method is the most philosophically rigorous way. Otherwise you're basically just saying "I want this structure to accurately model reality, therefore it does accurately model it".

Comment: @JackM I don't think he was making any claims whatsoever about what does or doesn't accurately model reality. It's more like he's saying "A vector space works like this. We'll leave reality to the engineers."
Whether something is accurately modeled is a question for empirical evidence, not a mathematical axiomatic definition.

Comment: @Yakk beware the chicken and the egg: you say the axioms are unproven facts about vectors spaces. What precisely are these vector spaces you are talking about ? We resolve this problem by throwing away this silly notion that there are some fundamental truths about something we don't even have a clear deflnition of, and instead we simply define it. Once the definition is there you don't need any more magic talk about unprovabale truths.

Comment: @Shufflepants What he was saying is that the classical notion of an axiom as an obviously true fact about the physical world is obsolete. This is not true. It's remains the best method of justifying that a mathematical model is an accurate one.

Comment: @JackM I disagree. Empirical data is only way to justify that a mathematical model is an accurate one. Just look at the history of the discovery of non-Euclidean spaces. There's a double irony in that many assumed that real life is Euclidean, and took the parallel postulate as an obviously true fact. But not only are there other axiomatic systems that are perfectly consistent and lead to other other geometries, but experimental evidence shows us that General Relativity is correct and we live in a non-Euclidean space.

Comment: @Shufflepants How do you think we know that the cartesian equation for a line is accurate? Do you think we just guessed the equation, then graphed a hundred lines and measured a hundred points on each to check that each one fit an affine equation to within a certain error? Mere empirical obervation is a completely unsatisfying way to check how accurate a mathematical theory is. The most rigorous and most satisfying way is to assert a few obviously true axioms to act as a kind of bridge between reality and mathematics, and then deduce your results.

Comment: @JackM your point-of-view appears to be highly inconsistent. I would suggest reading Mac Lane's "mathematics; form and function" and Lakatos' "proofs and refutations". I would laso like to suggest that you take the discussion to chat to avoid this comment thread turning into a battle-field.

Comment: @JackM You're forgetting, there are no lines in real life. Only a bunch of things that can be roughly approximated as line segments.
"Mere empirical obervation is a completely unsatisfying way to check how accurate a mathematical theory is." I don't think you understand what 'accurate' means, unless you're talking about mathematical consistency rather than being an accurate model of real objects.

Comment: I'd move all this to chat because I've heard comments aren't for extended discussions, but I've never seen a "chat" button.

Comment: @IttayWeiss Why we need to call them axioms though? I mean instead of saying "If the listed axioms are satisfied" we could just say "if a set satisfies the following properties, then it is called a vector space", in the same way we define other mathematical objects.

Comment: @user599310 We don't have to call them axioms. What you suggested is perfectly legitimate and quite common. The word 'axiom' is used, perhaps, in order to psychologically elevate a property to a 'higher' status. It is linguistic, not semantic.

Comment: @IttayWeiss Thanks for that clarification. I just wanted to clear up this since the word 'axiom' appears when studying axiomatic systems where it behaves like a postulate (something we take for true). While here (for vector spaces) it behaves the same way with ordinary definitions (e.g. "a number is even iff ...").

Comment: @user599310 The definition of a vector space is just an ordinary definition. Just like the definition of an even number. Since vector spaces are quite important and enjoy a very rich general theory, we speak of the theory of vector spaces. We then typically elevate the definition of the subject of the theory to the syntactic level of axioms rather than 'mere' definitions. If, for whatever reason, even numbers were super important and enjoyed a rich theory, we might speak of the theory of even numbers. The mere definition "a number is even if it is twice a natural number" may then be an axiom.

Answer (score 5):

> My understanding of axioms is that they are base assumptions which are taken to be true.

In some sense, that is true here. They are the base assumptions you are allowed to make when someone gives you a tuple $(V,+,0,-,\cdot)$ and tells you "this is a vector space". If you know some first order logic: you could make the language of real vector spaces, which has function symbols $+,-,0$ and for each real number $r$ a function symbol $r\cdot$. Then the above axioms are all formulatable in the this language. (Edit: and you need to include the theory of the real numbers as well, which is left implicit here.) The models of this set of axioms are vector spaces; and to prove that something is a vector space, you prove that it satisfies those axioms.

> Yet from this definition, it's necessary to show that the axioms are "satisfied" for a specific set in order to conclude that the set is a vector space. Is that somehow different than "proving" the axioms are true for the given set?

Not really, except for the very subtle difference that something can be true without being provable. If someone asks you "is this tuple a vector space", your only recourse is showing that all the axioms hold, or that one of them does not.

Answer (score 2):

The axioms are defined to be true for vector spaces.

When you are trying to show that something is a vector space, you are in fact **verifying** (not "proving") that the axioms hold.

It is a bit of wordplay here.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to think of this in programming terms:

In mathematics there are certain *objects* which fall into certain *classes*; an example of a mathematical class is 'vector space'.  The axioms define the *interface* of the class; the theorems derivable from these axioms in effect explore the kinds of computations that can be done using only the operations provided by the interface (plus some basic logic etc.).  By showing that a mathematical object *satisfies* the axioms, you are not trying to compute the features of the interface from anything else; rather, you are trying to show that *that object **implements** that interface*.  To do that, you have to identify which operations of the object (if any!) correspond to which operations of the interface (and -every- interface operation has to be matched!), and show that matching operations 'behave' the same.